# Lower semi-continious, compactum, minimum

Tags: continuity

> > Let $M$ be a topological space, $K\subset M$ compact, $f\colon M\to\mathbb{R}\cup\left\{+\infty\right\}$ lower semi-continious. Show that $f$ takes its minimum on $K$.

Good day,

we defined lower semi-continuity as follows: $f$ is lower semi-continious on $M$ if for any $x\in M$ and any $\alpha < f(x)$ there is a neighbourhood $U\subset M$ of $x$ such that $\alpha<f(y)$ for all $y\in U$.

So my idea is the following.

$f$ is lower semi-continious on $K$. Take any $x\in K$ and $\alpha < f(x)$, then there is a neighbourhood $U_x\subset M$ of $x$ such that $\alpha < f(y)~\forall y\in U$.

So it is 
$$
K\subset\bigcup_{x\in K}U_x.
$$
Because of the compactness of $K$ there is a finite index set $I$ such that
$$
K\subset\bigcup_{i\in I}U_{x_i}.
$$
It is $f(y)>\alpha~\forall y\in U_{x_i}, i\in I$.

So for all $\alpha <\infty$ it is $f(x)>\alpha$ for all $x\in K$.

This means that it is $\inf_{x\in K}f(x)=-\infty$.

But do not know what to do with this result, is it helpful at all??

Comment: I mean, no. $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x) = |x|$ is continuous, hence lower-semi-continuous ; but $f$ does not take its minimum on the compact subset $[1,2]$ for instance. You need something more about $K$, or maybe you misformulated something. Do you mean that the infimum over $K$ of $f$ is actually a minimum?

Comment: $\alpha$ depends on $x.$ So you should write $\alpha_x.$ Since $K$ is compact you have $K\subset\bigcup_{i\in I}U_{x_i}$ with $I$ finite. Thus $f\geq \min_{i\in I}\{\alpha_{x_i}\},$ that is, $f$ is bounded from below.

Comment: @Patrick Da Silva The statement is, that because of the compactness of $K$ the lower semi-continious function $f$ takes its minimum on $K$. Another book says that then $f$ has a minimum of $K$. Do not know what is the better way to formulate it.

Comment: @mathfemi : The way I understand it my example is a counter-example to your statement. How is my example *not* a counter-example, if you believe you are right? Then perhaps I can understand your statement better.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123537/any-lower-semicontinuous-function-f-x-to-mathbbr-on-a-compact-set-k-sub

Comment: @ManuelFdzLpz Does Why is $f\geqslant\min_{i\in I}\left\{\alpha_{x_i}\right\}$?

Comment: Because, by definition of lower semi-continuity, in any $U_{x_i}$ you have $f(y)>\alpha_i\geq \min_{i\in I}\{\alpha_i\}$

Comment: Ok, but the statement is not totally clear to me now: Set $b:=\min_{i\in I}\left\{\alpha_i\right\}$. Then for each $x\in K$ it is $f(x)>b$. Why does $f$ has its minimum on $K$ now?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva The statement means that the restriction of $f$ to $K$ has a minimum. So your counterexample is not a counterexample; and this is good because the statement is true.

Comment: I only see that $\inf_{x\in K}f(x)=b, b:=\min_{i\in I}\left\{\alpha_{x_i}\right\}$. Not that the inf is a minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Manuel, the first step of your reasoning is wrong because the $\alpha$ depends on $x$.

However, your method of proof is quite correct, and with a minor adjustment it gives the statement you want. Here are the details.

Set $a:=\inf\{ f(x);\; x\in K\}$. This is well defined, but possibly equal to $-\infty$. It is enough to show that one can find $x$ such that $f(x)=a$. (In particular, this will show that $a>-\infty$).

Assume this is not true. Then, for any $x\in K$ you have $f(x)>\alpha$; so you can choose a *real number* $\alpha_x>a$ such that $f(x)>\alpha_x$.

Then your above reasoning (together with Manuel's comments) gives that one can find $x_1,\dots ,x_N\in K$ such that 
$$\forall x\in K\;: \; f(x)>\alpha:=\min (\alpha_{x_1},\dots ,\alpha_{x_N})\, . $$
It follows that $\inf\{ f(x);\; x\in K\}\geq\alpha$, i.e. $a\geq\alpha$; but this is  a contradiction since $\alpha_{x_1},\dots ,\alpha_{x_N}$ are *strictly* greater than $a$ and hence $\alpha>a$.