# Proof that a continuous function $f : [a,b] \to {\mathbb Q}$ is a constant function.

Tags: real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Continuous Functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112043/continuous-functions-from-mathbbr-to-mathbbq)

Let $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb Q$ be a continuous function. Prove that $f$ is a constant function.

Comment: This is your second question in quick succession. What have you tried?

Comment: I had some suggestions for your post, but it would have been a repeat of [what Prof Magidin has already suggested](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144461/prove-that-there-exists-a-point-a-in-a-such-that-c-a-inf-c-x-x#comment332847_144461). You already have a helpful answer below, but try to keep his advice in mind. Cheers,

Comment: Although I answered, I downvoted. I sometimes downvote questions that don't show that the poster has tried anything or shown any effort. But if you edit your question, I would be willing to undo that.

Comment: Also see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141768/totally-disconnected-space/141771#141771

Comment: how can you  prove  that function is constant,even by   known fact that it is continuous?Q means rational numbers(represented by  ratio form)you need  show additional  constraints

Comment: @dato: Note that the continuous image of a connected space is connected. Only connected components of $\mathbb Q$ are rationals. You can prove this without resorting to additional constraints. I do agree, however, that such question is hard to answer if the OP does not supply a survey of their current knowledge.

Comment: ok thanks  @ Asaf Karagila

Answer (score 6):

HINT:

Is $[a,b]$ connected? Is $\mathbb{Q}$?