# Existence of such points in compact and connected  topological space $X$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be a topological space which is compact and connected.

$f$ is a continuous function such that;

$f : X \to \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$.

Explain why there exists two points $x_0$ and $x_1$ in $X$ such that $|f(x_0)| \le |f(x)| \le |f(x_1)|$ for all $x$ in $X$.

Comment: You should explain what you've already tried, and whether or not you understand the concepts involved.

Comment: Notation: the double arrow should be a single arrow, and $0$ should be $\{0\}$. $$f:X\to\Bbb C-\{0\}$$ or $$f:X\to\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}\;.$$

Comment: Shouldn't this follow from compactness alone, or a I missing something?

Comment: I've tried to use X's being compact so it means that it is bounded and inf(X) and sup(X) are in X but I have no idea how to use path connected and locally connected properties

Comment: @Alina: You don't need to.

Comment: See also this question: [$X$ compact metric space, $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ continuous attains max/min](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109548/x-compact-metric-space-fx-rightarrow-mathbbr-continuous-attains-max-min)
or Corollary 3 in the ProofWiki article [Continuous Image of a Compact Space is Compact](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Image_of_a_Compact_Space_is_Compact).

Answer (score 2):

the composite $X \to \mathbb{C} \setminus 0 \to \mathbb{R}_{> 0}$ given by first applying $f$ then the norm of a vector is a continuous map. Since $X$ is compact so is the image of this map as a subset of $\mathbb{R}_{>0}.$ Moreover by assumption on $X$ this set is connected. Connected compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ are closed intervals. Then the claim follows.

Comment: You don't really need connectedness.

Comment: yes. still it works out :)

Comment: that proof is very nice, thank you @mland, I made everything overcomplicated I guess because of the given properties.

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(x)=|f(x)|$, observe that the complex norm is a continuous function from $\mathbb C$ into $\mathbb R$, therefore $g\colon X\to\mathbb R$ is continuous.

Since $X$ is compact and connected the image of $g$ is compact and connected. All connected subsets of $\mathbb R$ are intervals (open, closed, or half-open, half-closed); and all compact subsets of $\mathbb R$ are closed and bounded (Heine-Borel theorem).

Therefore the image of $g$ is an interval of the form $[a,b]$. Let $x_0,x_1\in X$ such that $g(x)=a$ and $g(x_1)=b$.

(Note that the connectedness of $X$ is not really needed, because compact subsets of $\mathbb R$ are closed and bounded, and thus have minimum and maximum.)

Comment: One could mention Heine-Borel by name...

Comment: @Matt: One could also mention other names. For example Cantor's theorem that a continuous function from a compact metric space into a metric space is uniformly continuous, and perhaps replace the metrizability of the domain by some generalized property like ultrafilters or so.

Comment: No since we're not trying to confuse the OP. We're trying to help them.

Comment: @Matt: Oh, right. :-P

Comment: : ) ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Perhaps a nitpick, but I always think of the Heine--Borel theorem as saying that closed and bounded subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ are compact, not the converse (which applies in every metric space).

Comment: @Jonas: I was always under the impression that the theorem was "iff".

Comment: @Jonas: Also to be correct, in the general setting of a metric space one has to require a set to be totally bounded, not just bounded. The notions coincide for $\mathbb R^n$, as you probably know.

Comment: @Asaf:  I'm just saying that a compact subset of a metric space is closed and bounded, and that is all that is used here, not the special fact about $\mathbb R^n$ that the converse holds, i.e. Heine--Borel or one half of it if you prefer.  It is true that total boundedness also holds, and conversely if a metric space is complete and totally bounded then it is compact (at least assuming choice), but none of that seems very helpful here.

Answer (score 2):

Define the function $g: X \to \mathbb{R} $ by $g(x) = |f(x)|$, which is continuous.  Since X is compact, the result follows by the [Extreme Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem#Topological_formulation).