# A compact subset question

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If $B$ is a compact subset of a metric space, how do you show that there exist points $x$ and $y$ such that the distance between them is equal to the diameter of $B$. Don’t know how to proceed. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First show the distance function $d: X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous (where $X$ is the space $B$ lives in). Then by definition of the diameter of $B$, there exists sequence $(x_n), (y_n)$ such that $d(x_n, y_n) \to \text{diam}(B)$. Then apply sequential compactness of $B$.

Answer (score 0):

by definition, the diameter $diam$ of $B$ is defined as $diam = \text{sup}_{x,y \in B}d(x,y)$. Now choose a sequence $(a_k,b_k) $ in $B$ converging to $diam$. Using compactness implies that the limit lies in $B$.

Answer (score 0):

B×B is compact.  d:B×B -> R is continuous.
d(B×B) = { d(x,y) : (x,y) in B×B } is compact.
Compact sets of reals include a minimum and a maximum value.

Answer (score 0):

The metric $d : X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function. Its restriction to $B \times B$ is a real continuous funtion defined on a compact set.

Therefore, [it attains its minimum](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/109548/144766) $(x_0, y_0) \in B \times B$.

Hence, $$d(x_0, y_0) = \min_{(x,y) \in B\times B} d(x,y) = \operatorname{diam} B$$

Comment: How do you show that d is continuous?

Comment: @JohnMitchell The product space $X \times X$ can be equipped with the metric $d_1((x,y), (x', y'))=  d(x,x') + d(y,y')$. For $(x,y), (x',y') \in X \times X$ we have
$$|d(x,y) - d(x', y')| \le |d(x,y) - d(x, y')| + |d(x,y') - d(x', y')| \le d(y,y') + d(x,x') = d_1((x,y), (x', y'))$$
so $d$ is uniformly continuous on $X \times X$.