# Show that there is a $c > 0$ such that $f(a) ≥ c$ for all $a ∈ A$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $X$ a topological space, A ⊆ X compact and $f : A → \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function with the property  that
$f(a) > 0$, $∀a ∈ A$. Show that there is a $c > 0$ such that $f(a) ≥ c, ∀a ∈ A$.
I thought to use the fact that if $A$ is compact  then $f$ is bounded and $f(A)$ is closed, so there is $x_1\in A$ such that $f(x_1)=\inf f(X)$ and if I know that for any $a\in A$ the function is bigger than zero, then $\inf f(x) \geq 0$. It seems to simple to be true however.

More on the result I used here [$X$ compact metric space, $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ continuous attains max/min](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109548/x-compact-metric-space-fx-rightarrow-mathbbr-continuous-attains-max-min)

Did I give a complete proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. Yes, $f(A)$ is closed, but you should explain why. It is closed because it is compact and it is compact because $f$ is continuous and $A$ is compact.
2. The fact that $\inf_{x\in A}f(x)\geqslant0$ is irrelevant here. What matters is that, since $f(A)$ is closed, $\inf f(A)\in f(A)$. So, there is some $a_0\in A$ such that $\inf f(A)=f(a_0)$, and then, for each $a\in A$, $f(a)\geqslant f(a_0)>0$. So, take $c=f(a_0)$.