# Why do we need the notion of a compact set to define a game?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, game-theory, information-theory, economics

$\textit{Definition:}$ $I$ is a finite set of players and and $G=((S^i)_i,g)$ is a compact game, that is given by a compact set of strategies $S^i$ for each player $i$ and by a continuous payoff function $g:S=\times S^i \to \mathbb{R}^{I}$. Also the set of mixed strategies is defined as $\Sigma^i=\Delta(S^i)$ which is a standard way in game theory and $g$ is extended to $\Sigma$ by $g(\sigma)=\mathbb{E}_{\sigma}g(s)$.

$\textit{Question 1:}$ Why do we need the notion of compact game (set) from topology? Can anybody give the intuition and/or an example?

$\textit{Question 2:}$ From the best of my knowledge, the index $\sigma$ in the operator of the expected value, i.e. $\mathbb{E}_{\sigma}$ denotes the probability measure of the environment that we work. In this case $\sigma$ stands for the mixed strategy which is a probability distribution over the set of pure strategies (if I am not mistaken). Does this mean that $\sigma$ coincides with the probability measure?

I updated my question. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, it was an old question that I broke it in three smaller ones, so as someone could answer...I guess you have not seen my older post some days ago @Jean Marie

Comment: Don’t most proofs of equilibria require compactness?

Comment: @Randall, indeed, but why? There is something more behind this...

Comment: "compact set of strategies" ... this is generalized from the classical "finite set of strategies".  To answer your questions, you would follow the basic theorems in the subject, and see where compactness is used.  So are you asking someone else to do this for you?

Comment: Excuse me @GEdgar but I can not understand what are you talking about. 
1. My question is clear isn't it?
2. You mention that I need to "follow the basic theorems in the subject", tell me which are these theorems?

Comment: compactness guarantees existence of various limits, and in particular maxima and minima of functions on that compact set. Much of game theory is about maximization/minimization, and compactness is one of the natural things that guarantees these max/min are present in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's hard to be certain about this assumption without seeing the full context, compactness is often assumed in order to **guarantee existence of a solution** to a problem. I'm assuming that that optimality of $g$ over $(S^i)_{i\in I}$ describes a solution of your game? If so, then the game is guaranteed to possess a solution, since
[continuous functions always achieve their extrema on compact sets.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109548/x-compact-metric-space-fx-rightarrow-mathbbr-continuous-attains-max-min)

If the assumption of compactness is dropped, we must use much more technical arguments to verify that a solution exists.

Comment: ok! Thanks! You can check in page 72 here https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.685.4204&rep=rep1&type=pdf for the basic definitions, but I think I understand now the logic!

Comment: @HungerLearn Happy to help! Yeah, it looks like this is assumed so we don't run into pathological examples where a solution might not exist.

Comment: I am updating the question a little...so @Zim you could check it again if you want